# CSWP "Value of a field on the Page" Questions/Issues

Tags: web-part, search, 2013, keywordquery

We're trying to create a seach query that grabs a content type based on a taxonomy field added to our custom Publishing Page content type. We seem to be having one of two issues:

1. We don't know how to call a field that has a space. We've been using the internal name `Department:{Page.EH_x0020_Department}` and also tried the display name `Department:{Page.EH Department}`. Neither work, nor does inserting `%20` between the two.
2. We just don't know how to call a managed-metadata page field. If we copy/paste the term we want returned into the title of the page `{Page.Title}`, the query works. Are we missing something that is extra for managed metadata fields?

I couldn't find anything aside from the basics on Google, I appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: I have gotten confirmation from Microsoft that this is indeed a bug with SharePoint 2013. I will update this with any solution I hear back from them.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be a bug, but for fellow travellers, I found this in [TechNet.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx)

> Dealing with spaces in values
>
> Search queries use the space character to tokenize query values
>   issued by users. When a query variable is expanded to a value that
>   contains a space, the complete value is enclosed in double quotations.
>   For example, for the query author:{User}, the expanded value becomes
>   author:"John Smith".
>
> If you don't want the value to be enclosed with double quotations —
>   for example, when concatenating multiple values — you can use the
>   escape character in the query variable. For example:
>   customProperty:”{\User.Name};{\User.ZipCode}” would become
>   customProperty:”John Smith;98109”.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly late to the game here, but for the benefit of anyone else that stumbles across this page, you can use the following to reference a Managed Metadata column called `MMSFieldName` in the CSWP:

`owstaxIdMMSFieldName:{Page.MMSFieldName}`

The reason for this is that the token is transformed to the GUID (TaxID) rather than the plain-text label value. In the above `owstaxIdMMSFieldName` would be the crawled property name - you cannot use a managed property for this purpose.